# Finding the number of 0s in a number of binary matrices in the same directory?

Tags: r, csv, binary-matrix

I am trying to get the number of 0s (or count of) in a number of binary matrix csv files? Is there an efficient way of doing this for multiple csv files at once?

I have read in all the csv files from the set working directory using this code but I am unsure where to go from here...

```
matrices <- list.files(pattern="*.txt")
matrices <- lapply(matrices, read.delim)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to create a logical matrix (`x == 0`) by looping through the `list` of data.frames (`sapply`) and use `sum`.  In case, there are `NA` values, use the `na.rm = TRUE` (by default it is `FALSE`)

```
sapply(files, function(x) sum(x == 0, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks so much @akrun! This works brilliantly! I am only a beginner of R so would this work with a matrix of strings too or would I need to use another function in place of sum such as count?

Comment: @Lynda  If your strings are `"0"`, it would match that, but if it is `"00"`, it needs to specify exactly as `==` is an exact matching operator and not a regex `"00" == 0`.  Also, pleasee check for leading/lagging spaces `" 0"` or `"0 "`.  In that cases, you need `trimws`

Comment: Ok great @akrun thanks for explaining! This makes sense to me now!